# Intellisense Documentation for Implementing CSS/SCSS in Razor File using Visual Studio

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013, sass

I use SCSS to make my CSS files using Visual Studio 2013 with Web Essentials.

When I am adding class selectors an item in my razor template, Intellisense pops up telling me what classes are available.

Is there any way of adding XML documentation to my SCSS so that this dialogue could display some additional information about what I am doing?

This is what shows now:
[image]

This is what I want it to do:
[image]